# how to update changes on view in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I have a charts that have a few options for user and I already implemented everything but not sure why I don't see any immediate changes when I click Delete Chart, Publish Chart or Unpublished Chart button. I can only see the result only after I refresh the browser.

I'm new to Angular so I'm wonder how to remove the selected chart immediately or make it disappear when delete button is click and also the same for publish and unpublish chart without having to refresh the browser. any help or suggestion will be really appreciated

```
  @Input() chart: Chart;
  data: ChartData;
  chartData: ChartData;
  hasError: boolean = false;
  maxisChartConfig: ChartConfig;
  hasChart: boolean = false;
  @Input() editMode: boolean;
  isTextChart: boolean = false;
  constructor(private chartService: ChartService, private router: Router, private dialog: MatDialog) { }
  isGrid: boolean = false;
  @Input() wsType?: WorkspaceType;
  isPublicWs: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.wsType) {
      if(this.wsType == WorkspaceType.public) {
        this.isPublicWs = true;
      }
    }
    this.generateChartConfig();
    if(this.chart.chartType == ChartType.text){
      this.isTextChart = true;
    }
    else if(this.chart.chartType == ChartType.grid){
      this.isGrid = true;
    }
    if (this.chart.data) {
      if(!this.isTextChart){
        this.hasChart = true;
      }
      this.chartData = this.chart.data;
    }

  }

  deleteChart() {
    this.chartService.deleteChart(this.chart.guid).subscribe((deleted) => {
      console.log(deleted);
    });
  }

  publishChart() {
    this.chartService.setChartPublished(this.chart.guid, !this.chart.isPublished).subscribe((published) => {
      console.log(published);
    });
  }
```

```
 <button mat-menu-item (click) = "deleteChart()" *ngIf = "chart.hasAccess && chart.canEdit && !chart.isPublished">Delete Chart</button>
<button mat-menu-item (click) = "publishChart()" *ngIf = "chart.canEdit && chart.hasAccess && !chart.isPublished && isPublicWs">Publish Chart</button>
<button mat-menu-item (click) = "publishChart()" *ngIf = "chart.canEdit && chart.hasAccess && chart.isPublished && isPublicWs">Unpublish Chart</button>
```

The will not run but I uploaded the full code for this component here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bepxss . Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me which code in which code section you are creating the charts ?

Answer (score 1):

After each function you can call oninit to reconstruct the charts after changes like this -

```
deleteChart() {
this.chartService.deleteChart(this.chart.guid).subscribe((deleted) => {
  console.log(deleted);
  this.ngOnInit(); // Add this line
});
```

}

///This is how i have refreshed variables in my case -

```
 saveWTPModel(){

    if(some condition){
          //Perform Save logic
 var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const httpOptions = { headers: headers };
    this.httpClient.post(environment.api_url + "/User/SavePriority", 
     this.finalWTPArray, httpOptions)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          if(response){
            this.alertService.success('Priorities Saved.');
//Once i have saved everything I am again calling the api to get the updated data from backend. This function again is called to get the updated Priorities.
            this.getWorkTypesPriority(this.loggedinUserId);

          }
          else{
            this.alertService.warning('Problem Occurred.');
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: HI thanks but still not working.. so basically I have multiple charts and I'm trying to delete some chart. It deleted in the backend but still showing in the UI. It only disappear after I refresh the browser

Comment: where you are creating your chartdata here and where you are binding it to UI ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean but it's just my UI is not updating immediatly.

Comment: UI is not updating because you are not Refreshing the data which you are binding with the chart. So as soon as perform any action you need to re assign that variable which you are using to  bind the chart.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend directly calling angular life cycle hooks.

Comment: Rishabh and @marcusshep so what should I do? can you help me out plss..thanks

Comment: the solution is simple, you need to re initialize that variable which is binding to charts in your click events. If you are calling an API to get data from backend then you need to call the api after your deletion/insertion takes place within that same event.

Comment: I mean can you show me how to do that.. I'm really new angular developer working on existing code base so I'm not really familiar with the implementation. can you show me pls.. I uploaded the full code for this component in stackblitz